# prevent texture from creating gaps on edges

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, antialiasing

The texture I'm using is doing filtering for the edges but it creates gaps for the extrusion.

In the photo
[image: Image of unwanted artifacts]

The yellow shape is the texture, the white shape is an extrusion and the red shape is the background.

The red background should not be seen between the face, the yellow shape, and the extrusion.

What approach should I use?

Comment: Are you using `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` for `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T`?

Comment: @genpfault for the ones in the screenshot, I did not. But I just tried GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL_REPEAT and GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER but none of those closed the gap.